# I would like to create increment and decrement operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a function like this [Increment/Decrements function with auto select qty range and highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kJzq.png)

I am new to javascript, I try to gather code from various source finally I construct to this stage. My Codes are

```js
function incrementValue() {   // qty increment max 999
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if(value<999){ value++; document.getElementById('qty').value = value; }
}
function decrementValue() {   // qty decrement
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if(value>1){ value--; document.getElementById('qty').value = value;  }
}
//radio value to text box display
function myFunction(browser) { document.getElementById("qty").value = browser;}
```

```css
table tr {border:3px solid #ccc;}
table tr th {color:#000;}
table td {padding:10px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>220</p>
  <div>
    <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" />
    <input name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1"type="text">
    <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" />
  </div>
  <table>
 <tr style="background:#f0f;"><th width="50">Select</th><th width="50">Qty</th><th width="50">Discount</th><th width="50">Price</th></tr>
 <tr><td width="50"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="qty_select" value="5" onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/></a></td><td width="50">5</td><td width="50">5%</td><td width="50">200</td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="radio" name="qty_select" value="10" onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/></td><td>10</td><td>10%</td><td>150</td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="radio" name="qty_select" value="15" onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/></td><td>15</td><td>15%</td><td>125</td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="radio" name="qty_select" value="20" onclick="myFunction(this.value)"/></td><td>20</td><td>20%</td><td>100</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to create all the function above mentioned image.

Comment: Ok, do you have a question?

Comment: yes, JJJ. I want to know next what to do and Ii created that correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that's called by onClick event from buttons or onChange event from input.

In that function set action to be run when number in specific interval.

It's really the basics of JS